# Sass: Modify a global variable in one class to be used in a different class?

Tags: sass

My intent is to have two types of classes, a group of classes that each sets a particular background color and one that sets the background alpha channel (*not* the opacity property). Ie:

```
.opacity-50 {
    $alpha: .5;
}
.bg-red {
    background-color: $my-red;
}
.bg-blue {...} .bg-green {...} etc.
```

Ideally I could add more colors and opacity levels and mix and match them as needed.

Afaik, the best way to apply opacity to a color would be `rgba($color, $opacity)`. The question is, how do I define the classes such that the variable in one can be referenced by the other?

The "best" I've been able to figure out on my own is to use a global variable, ie.:

```
$alpha = 1;
.opacity-50 {
    $alpha: .5 !global;
}
.bg-red {
    $background-color: rgba($my-red, $alpha);
}
```

But this doesn't work; it seems the `alpha: .5` declaration is not scoped to `opacity-50` like I expected.

This doesn't seem like a particularly novel usage, so I have to imagine there is a proper approach, but I can't figure out anything that wouldn't require me to make two versions of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately they're mutually exclusive. While `opacity` is a **property** in and of itself related to the element for which it's defined, the rgb**A** alpha channel is a **value** for another separate property (like `color`, or `background-color`, etc).

However, if you're not supporting something like Internet Explorer (which has reached end of life anyway so hopefully you're not) you can get what you're after pretty easily using just [CSS vars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) or you could apply the exact same technique using Sass vars by overriding the var value based on its usage as shown in the example below with the same concept.

I just happened to use css vars for the example below because I was lazy and just made the PoC in the SO code editor.

```css
.fifty-percent {
  --opacity: .5;
}

div {
  --rgb: 0, 0 ,255;
  --opacity: 1;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  background-color: rgba(var(--rgb), var(--opacity));
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="fifty-percent"></div>
```

Comment: I am not using the opacity property at all, probably a poor choice of variable names on my part. The opacity in my example is a proper sass $ variable, not the opacity property. I'll edit it. Id also prefer to avoid mixing css vars and sass as much as possible as it tend to make things a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work the way I want with the following pattern but, as I said in my original post, this requires me to define everything twice instead of having the color and opacity truly be separated.

```
.bg-red {
    background-color: rgba($myRed, 1);
    &.opacity-50 {
        background-color: rgba($myRed, .5);
    }
}
```

I'm not going to accept this since it doesn't properly answer my question, but I'll leave it here for anyone else.